# Is it possible to publish an app containing only a WebView on Appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, wkwebview

I want to make an app that will basically load an e-commerce site(Made by me). Is there any possibility to get rejected from the apple review team?

Comment: Yes extremely likely, the apple review guidelines (which you can google) list this as something they don't accept, as it doesn't serve much of a purpose. If you don't need an app, don't build one

Comment: I want to do same thing

Comment: can you please tell me, did they approved your build ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen countless webview apps get published on the App Store. If you provide enough value to your potential users and customers, your app has high changes of getting on the App Store. (But your store should have a top mobile-optimized UI!)

If you want to increase your chances, you use a service like Gonative.io to add even more custom native features (tab bar, side bar, Biometrics etc.)

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website.

So answer is yes.